# SQL Null return "stops" return in c++ using odbc

Tags: c++, sql, odbc

My table looks a bit like this

```
Table cards
|  CardId  |  cityName| eventName|  Colour|
|----------+----------+----------+--------|
|     29   |   "test" |   null   | "blue" |
|     2    |   null   |  "test   |  null  |
```

Let's say now that I do

```
 "select * from card where CardId = 29"
```

My return vector will contain: "test" and that's it. So it will essentially contain all the data BEFORE eventName. Same thing would apply to the following

```
 "select * from card where CardId = 2"
```

The C++ code connecting to the db:

```
void SqlConnection::sqlExecuteSelect(string *select) {

SQLCHAR DBName[20] = "PandemicMain";
SQLCHAR SQLStmt[4000] = { 0 };
SQLRETURN rc = SQL_SUCCESS;
ODBC_Class Example;
if (Example.ConHandle != NULL)

{

    rc = SQLConnect(Example.ConHandle, DBName, SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR *) "concordia", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR *) "University4", SQL_NTS);

    // Allocate An SQL Statement Handle 

    rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, Example.ConHandle, &Example.StmtHandle);

    rc = SQLExecDirect(Example.StmtHandle, SQLStmt, SQL_NTS);

    if (rc == SQL_SUCCESS)

    {

        // Define A SELECT SQL Statement  
        char* finalSelect = new char[select->length() + 1];
        std::strcpy(finalSelect, select->c_str());

        strcpy((char *)SQLStmt, finalSelect);

        // Prepare And Execute The SQL Statement  

            rc = SQLExecDirect(Example.StmtHandle, SQLStmt, SQL_NTS);

        // Display The Results Of The SQL Query  
        if (!rc == SQL_SUCCESS) {
            cout << "*************************** failed ***************" << endl;
        }
        if (rc == SQL_SUCCESS)

        {

            Example.GetResultset();
            Connection.colData = Example.colData;



            // At this point you would want to do something  

            // with the resultset, such as display it.  

        }

    }

    // Free The SQL Statement Handle  

    if (Example.StmtHandle != NULL)

        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, Example.StmtHandle);

    // Disconnect From The Northwind Sample Database  
    rc = SQLDisconnect(Example.ConHandle);

}
}
```

Odbc.h

```
#pragma once

////////////////////////////////////////
#include <windows.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include<sqltypes.h>
#include<sqlext.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



// Define The ODBC_Class Class
class ODBC_Class
{
  struct ColDescription
  {
    SQLSMALLINT colNumber;
    SQLCHAR colName[80];
    SQLSMALLINT nameLen;
    SQLSMALLINT dataType;
    SQLULEN colSize;
    SQLSMALLINT decimalDigits;
    SQLSMALLINT nullable;
  };
// Attributes
public:
    SQLHANDLE EnvHandle;
    SQLHANDLE ConHandle;
    SQLHANDLE StmtHandle;
    SQLRETURN rc;
    vector<ColDescription> cols;
    vector< vector<string> > colData;
    // Operations
public:
    ODBC_Class(); // Constructor
    ~ODBC_Class(); // Destructor
    SQLRETURN GetResultset();
    void DescribeColumns();
private:
    _inline SQLRETURN Describe(ColDescription& c);
    SQLRETURN GetColData(int colnum, string& str);
};
```

Odbc.cpp

```
 #include "ODBC.h"

//***************************CODE FROM 
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/127959-odbc-c-example/ 
*************************************/
// Define The ODBC_Class Class


// Define The Class Constructor
ODBC_Class::ODBC_Class()
{
// Initialize The Return Code Variable
rc = SQL_SUCCESS;
// Allocate An Environment Handle
rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &EnvHandle);
// Set The ODBC Application Version To 3.x
if (rc == SQL_SUCCESS)
    rc = SQLSetEnvAttr(EnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,
    (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, SQL_IS_UINTEGER);
// Allocate A Connection Handle
if (rc == SQL_SUCCESS)
    rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, EnvHandle, &ConHandle);
}

// Define The Class Destructor
ODBC_Class::~ODBC_Class()
{
// Free The Connection Handle
if (ConHandle != NULL)
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, ConHandle);
// Free The Environment Handle
if (EnvHandle != NULL)
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, EnvHandle);
}

// Get the data for one column and return the info in the form
// of a std::string.  The ODBC driver will make all necessary
// data conversions from whatever type the data is in the database
// to SQL_CHAR.  You could make this function more comples by 
// getting the return type as it appears in the database then constructing
// a VARIANT object to hold the data.
SQLRETURN ODBC_Class::GetColData(int colnum, string& str)
{
  SQLCHAR buf[255] = { 0 };
  if ((rc = SQLGetData(StmtHandle, colnum, SQL_CHAR, buf, sizeof(buf), NULL)) == SQL_SUCCESS)
      str = reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf);
 return rc;
}

//
// Define The ShowResults() Member Function
SQLRETURN ODBC_Class::GetResultset()
{
   // Get all column description
   DescribeColumns();
   // erase anything that's in the colData vector
   colData.clear();
   // fetch a row from the resultset
   while (SQLFetch(StmtHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS)
   {
       // vector of strings to hold the column data
       vector<string> col;
       string data;
       // column counter
       int i = 1;
       // get the data for each column and add it to 
       // the col vector
       while (GetColData(i, data) == SQL_SUCCESS)
       {
           col.push_back(data);
           ++i; // increment the column number
       }
       // add column data to the colData vector
       colData.push_back(col);
    }
   return SQL_SUCCESS;
  }

 // Get the description for one column in the resultset.
 // This was made a seprate function to simplify the coding
 SQLRETURN  ODBC_Class::Describe(ColDescription& c)
{
    return SQLDescribeCol(StmtHandle, c.colNumber,
         c.colName, sizeof(c.colName), &c.nameLen,
         &c.dataType, &c.colSize, &c.decimalDigits, &c.nullable);
}

// Get the description for all the columns in the resultset.
void ODBC_Class::DescribeColumns()
{
    ColDescription c;
    c.colNumber = 1;
     cols.clear();
    while (Describe(c) == SQL_SUCCESS)
   {
      cols.push_back(c);
       ++c.colNumber;
   }

 }
```

After using SQLGetDiagRec

I get the following message:

> SqlState: 22002

So I do know this means "Indicator variable required but not supplied"

Anyway to deal with this?

Comment: Actually, I don't know anything about ODBC - just was curious. My 1st guess was that you get something like a `char**` and some pointer arithmetic could solve your issue but: Googling a little bit provided [easysoft: UsingSelectWithParameterArrays](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/c/examples/UsingSelectWithParameterArrays.html) and [Dr.Dobbs: C Database Programming with ODBC](http://www.drdobbs.com/c-database-programming-with-odbc/184403098). It looks like, access to results of "select" requests is not quite trivial. May be, you should edit your question and show your C++ code.

Comment: Mhm good Idea. Although I'm very new to C++ ( especially the sql side of it) my Sql connection code is  taken from a website. I'll add it in; good idea

Comment: The code does not show how you bind the columns to the buffer and how you retrieve data: Using SqlBindCol(), or using SqlGetData(). What about SqlFetch()? What lib do you use / what is class `ODBC_Class`?

Comment: Ah My apologies. I thought I should've only put in the connection to the sql. Added it in  now.  Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error for a while. Basically the ODBC is trying to tell you that the value you are retrieving is NULL. It will do this with the last Param in **SQLGetData()**, you can find more information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetdata-function

The line:

```
  if ((rc = SQLGetData(StmtHandle, colnum, SQL_CHAR, buf, sizeof(buf), NULL)) == SQL_SUCCESS)
  str = reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf);
```

You need to change the NULL value you are passing in to something it can populate. That is the buffer that the ODBC will try and fill if it is a NULL value. It will always return the length of the column you return in this field (but will not fall over if you pass a NULL) unless it is returning a NULL in which case it needs it. Pass an SQLLEN in by ref and it should return as an SQL_NULL_DATA.

Comment: Actually you need the length field for other stuff as well, such as `char(N)` values (note that they are padded!) and even varchar values. Also, I also prefer using `SQL_WCHAR`, which can be converted to an `std::u16string` quite easily; SQLGetData will fail in modern ODBC SQL Server drivers if you don't. One last detail, if you use `SQL_WCHAR`, you usually end up dividing the length by 2 (UTF-16 does that...) -- and if you don't check for `SQL_NULL_DATA`, -1/2 will give 0, so you will get an empty string instead of a `NULL`.